# How to apply rowSums() in R to select top n rows on the basis of rowsum value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am reading my data from a csv file. I want to sum over rows of the read data, then I want to sort them on the basis of `rowsum` values. Now, I want to select number of rows on the basis of specified threshold on `rowsum` value. I gave a try on `tempdata.csv`, which contains following data:

```
>data <- read.csv("tempdata.csv")
>data

        X Doc1 Doc2 Doc3 Doc4
1    book    2    0    2    1
2   table    0    2    0    1
3    room    0    2    0    0
4   chair    0    0    2    0
5 speaker    0    0    0    0

>m <- data.matrix(data[2:length(data)], rownames.force=NA)
>(dimnames(m)[[1]] <- data[,1])
>rs1 <- rowSums(m, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Now I don't know how to combine rowsum values to the matrix 'm'. I am very new in R, I am not able write the optimized code to achieve this. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's best to give a reproducible example that users can input and work with themselves. try `cbind(m, rs1)`

Answer (score 1):

This will sort the `data.frame` or `data.matrix` by `rowSums`

```
m[sort(rowSums(m), index=T, decreasing=TRUE)$ix, ]
```

If you only want the rows that meet a threshold you don't need to sort

```
m[rowSums(m) > threshold, ]
```

If you want to add a column containing the `rowSum` values

```
m <- cbind(m, rowSums(m))
```

Comment: Maybe add a part about combining the rowSums output to the data matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @6pool for your answer. I used following code to achieve the goal.

```
data <- read.csv("tiny.csv")
data2 <- data[, 2:length(data)]
data2 <- transform(data2, sum=rowSums(data2))
(dimnames(data2)[[1]] <- data[,1])
data3 <- data2[order(-data2$sum),]
### specify the threshold to select the number of rows
threshold = 3
(data4 <- data3[data3$sum>= threshold, ])
```